# How do I add a link to my output file's path?

Tags: c#

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The Export will be avilable in {0}", folderPath)
```

folderPath here shows the path of my output file. So I want the messsage box here to show as

"The Export will be available in [C:\Test](http://C:%5C)."

I should be able to navigate to C:\Test by clicking on it. Help?

Comment: @Ofir Winegarten - That was for URL and this is for a local clickable folder path.

Comment: it is the same...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string filePath = @"C:/Test/testFile.txt";
string directory =  Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The Export will be avilable in {0}. Open Folder?",
   directory), "Open Directory", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
   MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory);
}
```

Comment: Although I would go for a custom dialog form, this is a quick and easy solution. Nice

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you use name spaces / references assuming custom dialog form does not come along with the VS 2012 package?

Comment: Also, this opens up only the root directory and not the folder in which the file is created. Any idea? @daniell89

Comment: Never mind,     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", folderPath) worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with messagebox.

What I recommend is for you to create your own form and then show it using

```
yourCustomForm.ShowDialog()
```

It is very easy to do and works perfectly, is flexible and you can customize as you wish. I use this approach myself and seen this used even in big projects

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you use name spaces / references assuming this does not come along with the VS 2012 package?

Comment: Yes I use namespaces. I have switched to VS 2015 Community now and later will update to VS 2017.